# Swift development pods

Tags: swift, cocoapods

is there some good tutorial where I can follow, is there a good tutorial for better understanding, the ones I find i just create the pod and them publish, there is no implementation for me start to develop my own

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a poorly formed question... But if you're asking how to use podfiles, this video works great: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MuMZZtQpB6Y
If you're trying to make a podfile, here you are: https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/making-a-cocoapod.html